# How to send data back into SignalR Hub

Tags: c#, signalr, signalr-hub

is it possible to directly send data back into SignalR Hub from the front end JS/JQ (im working with  lists and monitoring). For example take textbox input and plug it back into a list on the back end of the server? If any one can drop that 1 liner execution line would be also appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I assume you have something in your javascript like:

```
var chat = $.connection.signalRPushEvents;
```

Then later on you can do this in Javascript:

```
chat.server.BroadcastData(a, b, c);
```

Then the class you're extending Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hub with should contain a method with that signature which is what that Javascript will effectively be calling.

```
public void BroadcastData(int a, string b, double c)
{
    // Do something with Clients or whatever here
}
```

Comment: yep that works for me as well , i used the invoke instead of server will read up about the diffrence

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. If anyone has a better solution, please reply as I am new to this API.

```
hub.invoke('HubMethodName', 'DOM or Value for Insert');
```

Answer (score 0):

I am sure there is a possible way to send the message back using a callback in JS once the message is received. Have you tried creating a callback function for each time a message is sent, and adding what you receive in the callback(i.e. the message) to the list you may want to put on the server?